# Categorial description of the subposet of $\prod_{i \in I}P_i$ of all $x \in \prod_{i \in I}P_i$ with $\{i \in I \mid x_i = \bot_{P_i}\}$ cofinite

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

By a grounded poset, I mean a poset $P$ with a least element $\bot_P$.

**Definition.** Whenever $P$ is a family of grounded posets, write $\bigotimes_{i \in I}P_i$ for the subposet of $\prod_{i \in I}P_i$ consisting of all $x \in \prod_{i \in I}P_i$ such that $\{i \in I \mid x_i = \bot_{P_i}\}$ is cofinite.

*Example.* Let

1. $\mathbf{N}$ denote the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ of natural numbers
2. $\mathbb{N}$ denote the poset of natural numbers equipped with the usual order
3. $\mathbb{N}^\times$ denote the poset of non-zero natural numbers equipped with the divisibility order

Then there is an order isomorphism $f : \bigotimes_{n \in \mathbf{N}}\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^\times$ given as follows.

$$x \mapsto \prod_{i \in \mathbf{N}}p_i^{x_i}$$

(where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.)

**Question.** Is there a sleek category-theoretic description of $\bigotimes_{i \in I}P_i$?

Comment: Moreover, *addition* can also go through your example (so we can talk about partially ordered commutative monoids), and $\otimes_{n\in N}\Bbb N$ is then the *free* commutative monoid on countably infinite generators, i.e. is the *coproduct* of $\Bbb N$'s, and the order is induced by addition ($a\le b$ iff $\exists c:b=a+c$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $\bigoplus_{i \in I} P_i$ is the colimit of all finite products of some of the $P_i$; in symbols, $\bigoplus_{i \in I} P_i =\mathop{\mathrm{colim}}_{F \subset I, |F|<\infty} \prod_{i \in F} P_i$.

Comment: ... where the transition maps are given by "inserting" ground elements. This is all very similar to the tensor product of algebras. And as usual, this is more than just a similarity. Do the same for categories, then for enriched categories, then in particular for categories enriched in modules with one object, which are just algebras.